# Boto3: use 'NOT IN' for Scan in DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I've managed to make a filter expression for filtering items from Scan. Smth like:

```
users = [1, 2, 3]
table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('user_id').is_in(users) 
)
```

Can I somehow convert it from filtering to excluding, so I will get all users except those with ids 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found so far is to use boto3.client instead of table and low-level syntax. Smth like this:

```
lst_elements = ''
attr_elements = {}
for id in user_ids:
    lst_element += 'user' + str(id)
    attr_elements['user' + str(id)] = id

client.scan(
    TableName='some_table_name',
    FilterExpression="NOT (user_id IN ({}))".format(lst_element[:-1]),
    ExpressionAttributeValues=attr_elements
)
```

This solution works fine for me but looks really complicated. So if you know a better way to do it, please add your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily by using the `~` operator:

```python
users = [1, 2, 3]
table.scan(
    FilterExpression=~Attr('user_id').is_in(users)
)
```

Check out the `__invert__` overload implementation in [condition.py](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/boto3/dynamodb/conditions.py#L43), which is triggered by `~`.

Comment: If you think that's too hard to spot, you can also just import `Not` and use `Not(Attr...)`. Again, check the source code link above for details.

Comment: confirmed you can add Not from: `from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr, Key, Not`, and filter expression: `Not(Attr('id').is_in(prevent_on)` where prevent_on is a list of ids in my usecase